# Parsing GUID from string line

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have different option how my GUIDS could be stored as a string line.

```
1. Accessibility|5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024738c19e
2. 5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024738c19e;#5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024733d52d
3. |;#5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024738c19e;#SharePointTag|5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024733d52d
3. Business pages|;#5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024738cz13;#SharePointTag|5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024733d52d
```

Could you guys help me to with ideas how could I parse this tags and get List of Guids type in the end? Maybe regular expression could help in such situation?

Comment: Do you use all the examples you have given us? or are you looking to pick one of those examples as a way of storing your guid? Can you provide more info of what you are trying to do.

Comment: looking at your data structure, I am thinking that you need to get your data structure sorted first, decide on what delimiter you want to use. I can see `| , ; #`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're playing with Managed metadata, term store ID and term set ID :)

Just use a regular regexp (the "p" variable below):

```
string c1 = "Accessibility|5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024738c19e";
string c2 = "5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024738c19e;#5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024733d52d";
string c3 = "|;#5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024738c19e;#SharePointTag|5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024733d52d";
string c4 = "Business pages|;#5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024738cz13;#SharePointTag|5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024733d52d";
string p = @"([a-zA-Z0-9]{8}[-][a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[-][a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[-][a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[-][a-zA-Z0-9]{12})";

MatchCollection mc;

Console.WriteLine("#1");
mc = Regex.Matches(c1, p);
foreach (var id in mc)
    Console.WriteLine(id);

Console.WriteLine("#2");
mc = Regex.Matches(c2, p);
foreach (var id in mc)
    Console.WriteLine(id);

Console.WriteLine("#3");
mc = Regex.Matches(c3, p);
foreach (var id in mc)
    Console.WriteLine(id);

Console.WriteLine("#4");
mc = Regex.Matches(c4, p);
foreach (var id in mc)
    Console.WriteLine(id);
```

Wich output:

```
#1
5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024738c19e
#2
5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024738c19e
5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024733d52d
#3
5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024738c19e
5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024733d52d
#4
5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024738cz13
5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024733d52d
Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: You are missing A-Z in the last part of the pattern, correct one should be `([a-zA-Z0-9]{8}[-][a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[-][a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[-][a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[-][a-zA-Z0-9]{12})`

Answer (score 4):

```
var possibleGuids = myString.Split("|;#".ToCharArray(), 
                                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Guid g;
foreach(var poss in possibleGuids)
{
  if(Guid.TryParse(poss, out g))
  {
      // g contains a guid!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string sContent = "your data"; // any of your four forms of input
string sPattern = @"([a-z0-9]*[-]){4}[a-z0-9]*";

MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(sContent, sPattern );

foreach (var sGUID in mc)
{
    // Do whatever with sGUID
}
```

Comment: `5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024738cz13` will pass your pattern but `Guid.TryParse` return false for the same.

Comment: good solution! Thanks. But has a bug, it returns me just part of guid:5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd

Answer (score 1):

You can split string for example

```
 "fist|second".Split('|')
```

You once you get the string of GUID convert it to GUID using

```
 Guid = new Guid(myString);
```

For first line

```
var guid = new Guid("Accessibility|5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024738c19e".Split("|")[1]);
```

For second line

```
var myArray = "5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024738c19e;#5102d73a-1b0b-4461-93cd-0c024733d52d".Split(';');
var guid1 = new Guid(myArray[0]);
var guid2 = new Guid(myArray[1].Replace('#',''));
```

So you can go ahead like that..